# Entity Framework dynamic fields

Tags: entity-framework, architecture

I am designing a data entry application using EntityFramework (Code First) to collect customers detail.

The data structure required is simple.

Customer entity has some flat and one-to-many details (eg. Name, Telephone Numbers, etc.) and then a large number of many-to-many properties which always follow the same pattern which allow for multiple choice from a list (in the UI, this would be shown as a checkbox list), which the user can also add items to. For each of these multiple choice properties, there is also one Notes property that allow the user to explain why these details where connected to the customer (in other words, this is just a string within the Customer entity).

Because of the similarity of these properties and the relative simplicity of the data, I started looking to model using inheritance however I am now thinking that perhaps there are better ways to achieve this, especially because there would be a major benefit if the system allowed an admin user to add a new property of this type dynamically.

I am looking for any suggestions to achieve this without having to define and connect all the entities manually or at least to minimize the amount of code required to do so.

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not know the concept of inheritance. However there are several strategies to let entity framework accept your inherited classes. Which strategy you ought to use depends on the type of queries you will ask most.

Suppose you have two classes `Student` and `Teacher`. Both classes have a lot of properties (and possibly methods) in common. You'd like to put them in a base class: `Person`. You don't want to be able to create a `Person` object, so your `Person` class will be abstract.

In C#:

```
abstract class Person
{
    ... // common person properties
}

class Teacher : Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}    // Primary Key
    ... // Teacher properties
}

class Student : Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}    // Primary Key
    ... // Student properties
}
```

You are not planning to create `Person` objects, only `Teachers` and `Students`. Therefore you could create a `Teachers` table and a `Students` table. The `Teachers` table contains all `Teacher` properties plus all `Person` properties. Similarly a `Student` table contains the `Student` properties and all `Person` properties. For every concrete (= non-abstract) class you create a table.

This strategy is called [Table-Per-Concrete-Class (TPC)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines). It is very similar to a composition: a Teacher 'has' Person properties, instead of inherits Person properties. It follows the old adagium "[Favour composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)"

You inform entity framework that you want this strategy in your `DbContext`

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers {get; set;}
    // we don't want a Person table, so no DbSet<Person>

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Tell entity framework that the Teacher Table will include Person properties
        modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
        });

        // Tell entity framework that the Student table will include Person properties
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
        });            
    }
}
```

A query for "Give me all Teachers who ..." or "Give me the Students that ..." will involve one table. However, if you ask: "Give me all Persons that ..." will require a concat of two tables.

```
var result = myDbContext.Teachers.Cast<Person>()
    .Concat(myDbContext.Students.Cast<Person>())
    .Where(person => ... // something with Person properties)
    .Select(person => ... // something with Person properties);
```

Whenever I need to model inheritence, I use this TPC strategy most of the time.

If you think that you'll be querying quite often for `Persons` that ... instead of `Teachers` who ..., consider using [Table Per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)

In TPT you'll have three tables: a `Person` table, containing all the `Person` properties, a `Teacher` table with the `Teacher` properties and a foreign key to the `Person` properties of this `Teacher`. Similarly you'll have a `Student` table with a foreign key to the `Person` properties it inherits.

Asking for "all Persons that ..." will only involve one table, whether the Person is a Student or a Teacher. Because you ask for Persons, you don't want any Student properties.

Asking for "all Teachers that ..." will always involve two tables, namely the Teacher table to get the Teacher properties and the Person table to access the Person properties.

So if you ask more often for "Persons who ..." that for "Teachers who ...", consider using TPT.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What you wrote about inheritance is very helpful however I am interested to find out more about the concept of storing new entities dynamically and implementing many to many relations.

Comment: Storing a new Element in one of the DbSet is using DbSet.Add: Teacher teachterToAdd = new Teacher(); myDbcontext.Teachers.Add(teacherToAdd); myDbContext.SaveChanges();<br> Many-to-many: visit http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Sorry I mean dynamic entities that are not defined concretely in code...